# Need suggestion on usage of cloud file storage system, where reads are more than writes

Tags: amazon-s3, filesystems, cloud, storage, cloud-storage

I need a cloud service for saving file objects for my project.
Requirements:
1. Pushing the files would be less compared to reading files from the storage.
2. Need to maintain versions of the file objects
3. File objects must be indexed for fast retrieval.

Note:
We have already considered using Amazon S3 bucket, but considering our project requirement, as reading the file objects would be 1 million times more than writing a file into storage.
As Amazon charges S3 usage more on the number of reads that writes it really is the last option for us to use.

Can anybody kindly provide suggestions on what can we use here?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're reading the file via HTTP, have you considered fronting S3 with CloudFront? Maybe that'd be a viable solution for you.

Comment: *"As Amazon charges S3 usage more on the number of reads that writes"* ...you might want to look at the pricing tables, again.  S3 reads are less than 1/10th of the cost of writes.  Depending on region, 1M writes = $5.00, 1M reads = $0.40.

Comment: thank you for your responses @Dunedan and Michael.. I have gone through the cost chart. as of now we are doing an R&D on utilizing S3 bucket for our requirements